# org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 15):Method call: Method getId() cannot be found on java.util.ArrayList type

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, jsf-2, primefaces

I need help fixing this error, in the first place I want to get all commands then when I choose one I should get more detail about command chosen.

BaseEntity.java

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long              id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId( Long id ) {
        this.id = id; 
    }
}
```

Command.java

```
 @Entity
 @Table( name = "cmd" )
 public class Command extends BaseEntity {

     String private name;

     //getter&setter

 }
```

CommandDao.java

```
public Command loadById( Long id ) {
    Assert.notNull( id );
    Command cmd = null;
    Query query = getEntityManger().createQuery( "select u from "
            + getPersistentClass().getSimpleName()
            + " u where u.id= :id" ).setParameter( "id", id );
    try {
        cmd = (Command) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch ( NoResultException e ) {

    }
    return cmd;
}

@Override
@Transactional( readOnly = true )
public List<Command> listeCmd() {
    Query query = getEntityManger().createQuery( "from " + getPersistentClass().getSimpleName() );
    List<Command> cmd = (List) query.getResultList();
    return cmd;
}
```

CommandServiceImpl.java

```
   private CommandDao      commandDao;

   public List<Command> list() {
       return commandDao.listeCmd();
   }

   public Command cmdPick( Long id ) {

       List<Command> l = Command Dao.listeCmd();
       Command cmd = null;
       for ( int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++ ) {
           if ( l.get( i ).getId() == id ) {
               cmd = commandDao.loadById( id );
           }
       }
       return cmd;
   }
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="commandDao" class="xx.xx.xx.CommandDao" />

<!-- Services Declaration -->
<bean id="commandService" class="xx.xx.xx.CommandServiceImpl">
    <property name="commandDao" ref="commandDao" /></property>
</bean>
```

flow.xml

```
<var name="command" class="xx.xx.xx.Command" />

<view-state id="shwo" view="show.xhtml" model="command">

    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="commandService.liste()" result="viewScope.list"/>
    </on-render>

    <transition on="pick">
        <evaluate expression="commandService.cmdPick(command.getId())"
         result="flowScope.list" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

Show.xhtml

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{list}">
    <p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{car.name}" />
    <h:commandLink action="pick" value="#{car.id}"/>
       </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Error

> 12:57:22,883 DEBUG ActionExecutor:49 - Executing [EvaluateAction@1360f6d expression = commandService.commandService.cmdPick(command.getId()), resultExpression = flowScope.command]
>   12:57:22,883 DEBUG AnnotatedAction:142 - Putting action execution attributes map[[empty]]
>   12:57:22,884 DEBUG AnnotatedAction:149 - Clearing action execution attributes map[[empty]]
>   12:57:22,886 DEBUG FlowExecutionImpl:590 - Attempting to handle [org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@127eb1c targetAction = [EvaluateAction@1360f6d expression = commandService.commandService.cmdPick(command.getId()), resultExpression = flowScope.command], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'show' of flow 'main' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause [org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 15): Method call: Method getId() cannot be found on java.util.ArrayList type]
>   12:57:22,886 DEBUG FlowExecutionImpl:611 - Rethrowing unhandled flow execution exception
>   12:57:22,887 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:99 - Unlocking conversation 1
>   mai 31, 2014 12:57:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path [/Colocation] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@127eb1c targetAction = [EvaluateAction@1360f6d expression = commandService.commandService.cmdPick(command.getId()), resultExpression = flowScope.command], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'show' of flow 'main' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 15): Method call: Method getId() cannot be found on java.util.ArrayList type
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:182)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:106)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:65)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
>       at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.ActionTransitionCriteria.test(ActionTransitionCriteria.java:82)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.TransitionCriteriaChain.test(TransitionCriteriaChain.java:71)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.canExecute(Transition.java:195)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:211)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
>       at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: Try to show more info about StackTrace on the matter

Comment: The problem is that `commandService.liste()` returns a list, but you are not using it as a list since you are calling `command.getId()` on it. You probably want to iterate through the list and call the method on each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying model for form as command and viewscope variable also as command on render. Change this viewscope variable to commandList and make corresponding change in view as well. Then in commandLink write a JavaScript onclick function to capture the id selected by user and assign it a field in Command. Lets say this field defined as selectedId in model command. Pass this value to cmdPick method in evaluate expression.

Comment: I meant to change literal name of viewscope variable to not to clash with model name of view. BTW I don't see 'commandList' in your service.

Comment: I edited my publication, can you please tell me if it is correct ? about viewScope

Comment: Yup it's good. Give unique names for scope variables always. Now just write a js function and try.

Comment: sorry Prasad for my question but can you give me more detail about second part in your explanation

Comment: You have list of commands. You want to select one id from it right. So in command entity create a transient field by name selectedId  and set this field with id selected by using JavaScript onclick function. Unfortunately I don't have access to computer now.